# Как полностью вывести содержимое переменной, без многоточия?

Tags: python, print, pandas

Есть переменная, которая содержит много данных.

Вывод у нее выглядит следующим образом:

```
['A312', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A419', 'A321', 'A323', 'A679', 'A319',
       'A325',
       ...
       'A812', 'A841', 'A835', 'A747', 'A814', 'A840', 'A843', 'A774', 'A850',
       'A864']
```

Как сделать, чтобы выводились все значения без многоточия, т.е. не проходя по ней циклом?

Вывожу объект класса `pandas.indexes.base.Index` обычным способом:

```
print(variable)
```

---

IDE: Sublime Text 3

Comment: Обычный `print` выводит данные полностью. Укажите в вопросе код, с помощью которого вы делаете вывод. Также укажите, используете ли IDE (PyCharm, например).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите параметр `pd.options.display.max_rows` по своему усмотрению для вывода на экран строк DataFrame/Series/Panel/etc. для Pandas и `np.set_printoptions(threshold=XXX)` для `numpy`, где `pd`, `np` - классические алиасы для `pandas` и `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Учтите, что эти параметры никак не влияет на вычисления, эскпорт данных (to_csv/to_excel/to_hdf/to_html/etc.) и т.д. - они только ограничивают вывод на экран...

Demo:

показываем максимум 20 строк:

```
In [204]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 20

In [205]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(30, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

In [206]: df
Out[206]:
     A   B   C
0   63  36  61
1   95   5   2
2   14  87   1
3   17  94  56
4   13   5  79
5   68  27  91
6   18  26  28
7   85  31  60
8   81  21  26
9   25   2   2
..  ..  ..  ..
20  93  30  92
21  92  77  37
22  49  78  50
23  47  10  31
24   1  54  79
25  10  99  77
26  26  36  18
27  56  56   7
28  32  39  33
29  91  76  81

[30 rows x 3 columns]
```

показываем максимум 100 строк:

```
In [207]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 100

In [208]: df
Out[208]:
     A   B   C
0   63  36  61
1   95   5   2
2   14  87   1
3   17  94  56
4   13   5  79
5   68  27  91
6   18  26  28
7   85  31  60
8   81  21  26
9   25   2   2
10  70   3   2
11  64  13  81
12  37  11  27
13  75   9   1
14  11  57  39
15   8  76  11
16  18  81  64
17  28  31  40
18  36  69  91
19  58  36  80
20  93  30  92
21  92  77  37
22  49  78  50
23  47  10  31
24   1  54  79
25  10  99  77
26  26  36  18
27  56  56   7
28  32  39  33
29  91  76  81
```